# Upgrading VS test professional to 2013 and still working with VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing

Is there any problem with visual studio vs 2010 ultimate with visual studio test professional 2013 and tfs 2013, while creating coded UI tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using VS2010 or VS2013 for CodedUI tests but not both. Trying to run 2010 CodedUI tests in 2013 will attempt an upgrade I think.  Trying to run 2013 tests in 2010 will likely fail. There is no problem using VS2010 or VS2013 CodedUI with TFS 2013 just make sure you install VS2010 on your build agent.

Comment: I finally did it, manage some tests, need to do some "manualy build some dlls" but finaly working.

Answer (score 0):

I made this working, but now have another problem.

I cant export results (test plan, test run summary).

When i try to do some export i got this error:

Compiling transformation: Assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'